# How to generate SqlDataProvider for 2 db connection

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a 2 DB connection, db and db2. I want to get all data from table claim in db2 connection. Below is my sql and it did not read from db2 connection. How to solved this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM claim where provider_id = xx ";
$sql_count = "SELECT COUNT FROM ( $sql ) AS count ";
$totalCount = Yii::$app->db2->createCommand($sql_count)->queryScalar();
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
'sql' => $sql,
'totalCount' => $totalCount,
'sort' =>false, 
'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
return $dataProvider;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to configure your databases like below:

```
return [
'components' => [
    'db1' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1name', //maybe other dbms such as psql,...
        'username' => 'db1username',
        'password' => 'db1password',
    ],
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db2name', //maybe other dbms such as psql,...
        'username' => 'db2username',
        'password' => 'db2password',
    ],
],
];
```

Then you can simply :

```
//to get from db1
Yii::$app->db1->createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)->select('*')->from('tbl_name'))->queryAll()
```

//to get from db2

```
Yii::$app->db2->createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)->select('*')->from('tbl_name'))->queryAll()
```

If you are using an active record model, in your model you can define:

```
public function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->db1;
}
```

//Or db2

```
public function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->db2;
}
```

Then:

if you have set db1 in getDb() method, result will be fetched from db1 and so on.

```
ModelName::find()->select('*')->all();
```

Comment: I already have all the configuration. The sql the I provide before is on claim model on db2 and this sql is being call from another model on db connection. When I do print_r($dataProvider) the database name is from db connection not from db2. Is it because I called the function from model on db connection ?